# What are the best apps for students to discuss math problems?

Tags: secondary-education, mathematical-pedagogy, technology-in-education, interactive-teaching

I am looking for a good app that enables students to chat with one another in order to work on mathematics problems.  The idea is that, in the old days, students would work over the phone to solve math problems; these days, they are more inclined to chat using apps.
I would like to provide students with that option so that they can work collaboratively in their own voice (so to speak).

To this end:

> What are the best apps for students to discuss math problems?

Comment: How about google hangout?

Comment: Look into MathJax. It is a browser extension that allows for Latex rendering.

Comment: You may wish to rename this question more accurately.

Comment: A distributed whiteboard-type app? There are a number of them, such as [this](https://awwapp.com/) and [this](http://www.wischik.com/damon/Work/Interests/Chalk/)

Comment: Benjamin Dickman, the reason I put this as mathematics literacy is that I am endeavouring to get students 'talking' and working collaboratively using the social nature of language to increase their mathematical learning.  Sorry if I threw you off.

Comment: Since there has been no response for over a month, I have edited the post name to reflect the question more accurately. If there are any issues with these edits, please feel free to re-edit or revert them.

Answer (score 3):

We use Google Hangouts as a part of a Google Apps for Education deployment. It allows pupils to chat in real time, and allows the school some degree of control over this space.
Apart from this, I think you can be pretty much assured that the pupils in your class will have their own strategies to solve this problem. They may not use them much for Maths, though!

Comment: Thank you all for your responses - they have been really helpful.  Nickjamesuk, I think I will use your suggestion.  Once again - really helpful everyone.

Comment: @Michelle If you want someone to be told you've addressed them, you should put the @ symbol at the start of their screen-name. (I notice that twice you have not done so.)